# Error Nmap NSE http-form-brute

Tags: brute-force, nmap

I'm trying to get some time using the http-form-brute script, but every time it says that the path is wrong, but I already checked the path, yes, I also checked the syntax and it looks correct ... Point where I'm going wrong.

```
Starting Nmap 7.25BETA1 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-12 19:48 UTC
--------------- Timing report ---------------
hostgroups: min 1, max 100000
 rtt-timeouts: init 1000, min 100, max 10000
 max-scan-delay: TCP 1000, UDP 1000, SCTP 1000
 parallelism: min 0, max 0
 max-retries: 10, host-timeout: 0
 min-rate: 0, max-rate: 0
---------------------------------------------
NSE: Using Lua 5.2.
NSE: Arguments from CLI: userdb=d.dic,passdb=d.dic,http-form-        
brute.uservar=usuario,http-form-brute.passvar=senha,http-form-brute.onfailure=invalido!,http-form-brute.path=/admin/validar.php
NSE: Arguments parsed: userdb=d.dic,passdb=d.dic,http-form-brute.uservar=usuario,http-form-brute.passvar=senha,http-form-brute.onfailure=invalido!,http-form-brute.path=/admin/validar.php
NSE: Loaded 1 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 19:48
Completed NSE at 19:48, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 19:48
Scanning www.laboratoriohacker.com.br (31.170.164.209) [4 ports]
Packet capture filter (device wlan0): dst host 192.168.0.102 and (icmp or icmp6 or ((tcp or udp or sctp) and (src host 31.170.164.209)))
We got a ping packet back from 31.170.164.209: id = 1632 seq = 0 checksum = 63903
Completed Ping Scan at 19:48, 0.52s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Overall sending rates: 7.76 packets / s, 294.96 bytes / s.
mass_rdns: Using DNS server 192.168.0.1
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:48
mass_rdns: 0.01s 0/1 [#: 1, OK: 0, NX: 0, DR: 0, SF: 0, TR: 1]
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 19:48, 0.01s elapsed
DNS resolution of 1 IPs took 0.01s. Mode: Async [#: 1, OK: 0, NX: 1, DR: 0, SF: 0, TR: 1, CN: 0]
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 19:48
Scanning www.laboratoriohacker.com.br (31.170.164.209) [1 port]
Packet capture filter (device wlan0): dst host 192.168.0.102 and (icmp or icmp6 or ((tcp or udp or sctp) and (src host 31.170.164.209)))
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 31.170.164.209
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 19:48, 0.31s elapsed (1 total ports)
Overall sending rates: 3.24 packets / s, 142.60 bytes / s.
NSE: Script scanning 31.170.164.209.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 19:48
NSE: Starting http-form-brute against www.laboratoriohacker.com.br (31.170.164.209:80).
NSE: [http-form-brute 31.170.164.209:80] Form submission path: /admin/validar.php
NSE: [http-form-brute 31.170.164.209:80] HTTP method: POST
NSE: [http-form-brute 31.170.164.209:80] Username field: usuario
NSE: [http-form-brute 31.170.164.209:80] Password field: senha
NSE: [http-form-brute 31.170.164.209:80] Failed to get new session cookies:        Unable to retrieve a login form from path "/admin/validar.php"
NSE: Finished http-form-brute against www.laboratoriohacker.com.br (31.170.164.209:80).
Completed NSE at 19:48, 1.35s elapsed
Nmap scan report for www.laboratoriohacker.com.br (31.170.164.209)
Host is up, received echo-reply ttl 52 (0.46s latency).
Scanned at 2017-01-12 19:48:02 UTC for 2s
PORT   STATE SERVICE REASON
80/tcp open  http syn-ack ttl 52
| http-form-brute:
|_  ERROR: Failed to submit the form to path "/admin/validar.php"
Final times for host: srtt: 457110 rttvar: 414875  to: 2116610

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Initiating NSE at 19:48
Completed NSE at 19:48, 0.00s elapsed
Read from /usr/bin/../share/nmap: nmap-payloads nmap-services.
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.02 seconds
       Raw packets sent: 5 (196B) | Rcvd: 2 (72B)
```

Comment: What version of Nmap? Are you using the latest (7.40 as of December 20, 2016)? What is the output with `-d`? What about with `--script-trace`?

Comment: Yes, nmap is in the latest version 7.40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided the path to the HTML form as `/admin/validar.php`, but the script is unable to GET a response containing a form from that page. Most likely, this is the path that the form POSTs to, not the page that the form exists on. The path provided should be the URI path that a user sees in his browser when filling out the form. Alternatively, you can try setting `sessioncookies` to 0 (false) to avoid the form detection, but if the form requires new cookies for each submission, then brute forcing will not be possible.